# trying to get json stuff into an array but i can't get it out

Tags: jquery, json

Okay, I think I may be retarded, but I can't figure this out for some reason.

I have this code.

```
var x = [];

$.getJSON('data.json', function(data) { 
    $.each(data, function(key, val) {
        x.push(val);
    });
});

console.log(x);
```

It prints this to console.

[image: output]

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to access x or y. Can someone explain to me how this works?

json:

```
[
 {
   "x": 121.87375,
   "y": 483.7810417
 },
 {
   "x": 116.831875,
   "y": 471.9985417
 },
 {
   "x": 111.694375,
   "y": 460.0341667
 }
]
```

I just want to be able to do a for loop and update x and y to the next index every second.

Comment: instead of link post an image together with the OP

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show what the content of `data.json` is, and what the corresponding desired output of your JS is. For the `x` array that you show that was logged in the console, you could say `x[0].x` and `x[0].y` to get the coordinates of the first item in the array.

Comment: Your `console.log` is happening before the XHR request comes back, which is why it is printing an empty array. Move the `console.log` into the callback, after the `$.each` loop.

Comment: Related: [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Comment: @nnnnnn I tried x[0].x it gives a cannot read property of undefined. Basically the x array is always undefined.

Comment: @UselessCode I want to be able to access the data outside of the get json. More specifically I want to loop through each index and update x and y every second. Is this possible or does it have to be within the getjson?

Comment: It's undefined because of what Jonathan's link explained about async code.

Comment: Oh. I just gave it a setTimeout of 1000ms and it worked fine. Guess I'm retarded. Thanks.

Comment: No, don't just delay your other code with `setTimeout()` - what if you have a slow connection and it takes 1200ms for the Ajax to run, or 2200ms? Code that needs the results should either be in the `$.getJSON()` callback or called from there. (Or you could restructure a bit to use promises instead.)

Comment: I'm not familiar with promises. Is that a way to execute code after the ajax is confirmed to be finished?

Comment: I added .done(function() { } and added my code inside there and it seems to work. Is that more correct?

Answer (score 0):

`$.getJSON` is asynchronous, the data is not inside of `x` when you call `console.log` immediately after you make the `getJSON` call. You have to wait for the network request to finish before you can use the data it is retrieving.

There are a couple of ways you could make it work. The traditional approach would be to use data inside of the callback after you receive it by moving `console.log` there:

```js
var jsonData = [{"x": 121.87375,"y": 483.7810417},{"x": 116.831875,"y": 471.9985417},{"x": 111.694375,"y": 460.0341667}];
$.getJSON = function fakeGetJSON (url, callback) {
  setTimeout(callback.bind(null, jsonData), 500);
};

var x = [];

$.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
  $.each(data, function(key, val) {
      x.push(val);
  });
  console.log(x);
  // call another function that uses x, etc.
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The second would be to use a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). jQuery AJAX calls return a [jqXHR object](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR). [As of version 3.0](http://blog.jquery.com/2016/05/20/jquery-3-0-release-candidate-released/) the jqXHR object is compatible with the Promises/A+ standard. If you are using a version before 3.0, you'll have to use [`.done`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/) instead of `.then`.

```js
var jsonData = [{"x": 121.87375,"y": 483.7810417},{"x": 116.831875,"y": 471.9985417},{"x": 111.694375,"y": 460.0341667}];
$.getJSON = function fakeGetJSON (url, callback) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function () {resolve(jsonData)}, 500);
  });
};

var x = [];

$.getJSON('data.json').then(function(data) {
  $.each(data, function(key, val) {
      x.push(val);
  });
  console.log(x);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You could also write it like this:

```js
var jsonData = [{"x": 121.87375,"y": 483.7810417},{"x": 116.831875,"y": 471.9985417},{"x": 111.694375,"y": 460.0341667}];
$.getJSON = function fakeGetJSON (url, callback) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function () {resolve(jsonData)}, 500);
  });
};

var x = [];

var dataPromise = $.getJSON('data.json').then(function(data) {
  $.each(data, function(key, val) {
      x.push(val);
  });
  return x;
});

dataPromise.then(function (data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

It should also be noted that unless you are doing more complicated processing in your real code, you don't need to loop over the data with `$.each`, the data that is being returned is already an array of objects:

```js
var jsonData = [{"x": 121.87375,"y": 483.7810417},{"x": 116.831875,"y": 471.9985417},{"x": 111.694375,"y": 460.0341667}];
$.getJSON = function fakeGetJSON (url, callback) {
  setTimeout(callback.bind(null, jsonData), 500);
};

var x = [];

$.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
  x = data;
  console.log(x);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Some Clarifications :**

1. `JSON` you are getting in `console` is already having an `array of objects`. What else you needed ?
2. If you want to access the value of `x` and `y` from the `JSON` then you can use JavaScript [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) or [for..in loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) methods to iterate the array object.

**Using map()**

```js
var jsonObj = [
 {
   "x": 121.87375,
   "y": 483.7810417
 },
 {
   "x": 116.831875,
   "y": 471.9985417
 },
 {
   "x": 111.694375,
   "y": 460.0341667
 }
];

var res = jsonObj.map(function(item) {
  return item.x;
});

console.log(res);
```

**Using for...in loop**

```js
var jsonObj = [
 {
   "x": 121.87375,
   "y": 483.7810417
 },
 {
   "x": 116.831875,
   "y": 471.9985417
 },
 {
   "x": 111.694375,
   "y": 460.0341667
 }
];

for(var i in jsonObj) {
  console.log(jsonObj[i].x);
}
```